# Virtual Entity Lookup not showing data on Portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

I have a requirement to show external data in Dynamics 365 on Case entity as Lookups. I am using virtual entity and developed custom data provider for the same. All lookups shows data properly on case form in CRM Web UI client. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

I have exposed that same case form on Portal, and when I try to select record from one of the Lookups on Portal, I'm getting the below error. Other Lookups work fine even though its pointing to same Custom Data Source. I have configured Employee Self-service portal.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Virtual entity feature with Portal solutions has some restrictions mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-edit-virtual-entities?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#considerations-when-you-use-virtual-entities) like below:

> Many features that affect entity table rows cannot be enabled with virtual entities. Examples include queues, knowledge management, SLAs, duplicate detection, change tracking, mobile offline capability, field security, Relevance Search, **Portals for Dynamics 365 web portal solutions**, and N:N relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this link. I have gone through this link before starting my POC on VE. First of all, there was caching issue on portal I was facing and second  with a specific limitation on filtered lookup. Apart from these, Virtual entities works fine on portal.